# How to control number of cores of a method

Tags: python, multiprocessing, joblib

I have the following code:

```py
from sklearn_extra.clusters import KMedoids

def _compute_medoids(df, k):
    k_medoids = KMedoids(n_clusters=k, metric='precomputed', init='k-medoids++').fit(df)
    medoid_index=k_medoids.medoid_indices_
    labels=k_medoids.labels_
    return medoid_index, labels


for k in range(1, 6):
    medoid_ids, labels = _compute_medoids(df, n_clusters=k)
```

Executing the code this way, I get a bad performance. Unlike `sklearn`'s models, `sklearn_extra.cluster.KMedoids` doesn't have a `n_jobs` parameter, and checking the core usage, most of the time the process is using just one core.

I tried to use `joblib`:

```
Parallel(n_jobs=os.cpu_count())(delayed(_compute_medoids)(df, k) for k in range(1, 6))
```

I got some performance improvement, but not enough for my task. And also, increasing the number of cores from 4 to 8 or 16 did not return a proportional amount of performance improvement.

As I understand, these multiprocessing libs like `joblib` or `multiprocessing` can control the number of workers in parallel, but not the core usage of the processing function. Am I right?

I was wondering if there exists a way to force `_compute_medoids` to be executed on a fixed number of cores, so that I can process as many workers I can (Example - Using 16 cores to set 4 workers to execute 4 `compute_medoids` method, each one using 4 cores). Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

The `kmedoids` package has faster algorithms, including a parallel version of FasterPAM.

https://python-kmedoids.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#kmedoids.fasterpam

```py
def _compute_medoids(df, k):
  import kmedoids
  km = kmedoids.fasterpam(df, k)
  return km.medoids, km.labels
```

Comment: Thank you! Didn't know it. Will help a lot :)